# suddebky - psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, postgis

I have a DigitalOcean droplet where `Django` project with `Postgres/PostGIS` database is running.

Suddenly it stopped working. When I want to connect to `psql` it says:

```
psql
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have no idea where is the problem.

Can this be an attack? I guess no as `UFW` wouldn't allow `postgres` connections from outside.

UFW

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I'd like to know if the data are still there and I want to connect again.

I've rebooted the server and now I can't see anything except today in:

```
sudo tail -n 1000 /var/log/auth.log
```

I don't know where to start looking for the problem. Can you help me?

The last logs:

```
sudo tail -200 /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log.1
2021-11-12 12:36:16.439 UTC [792] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2021-11-12 12:36:16.440 UTC [792] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2021-11-12 12:36:16.449 UTC [792] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 800) exited with exit code 1
2021-11-12 12:36:16.452 UTC [795] LOG:  shutting down
2021-11-12 12:36:16.482 UTC [792] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

**/var/run/postgresql/**

```
ls -la /var/run/postgresql/
total 0
drwxrwsr-x  3 postgres postgres  60 Nov 13 13:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 27 root     root     900 Nov 13 13:23 ..
drwxr-s---  2 postgres postgres  40 Nov 13 13:08 12-main.pg_stat_tmp
```

**syslog | grep "postgres"**

```
sudo tail -n 20000 /var/log/syslog | grep "postgres"
Nov 13 13:08:46 myproject-ubuntu kernel: [    4.082735] systemd[1]: Created slice system-postgresql.slice.
Nov 13 13:08:46 myproject-ubuntu postgresql@12-main[773]: Error: Could not open logfile /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
Nov 13 13:08:46 myproject-ubuntu postgresql@12-main[708]: Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log -s -o  -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf"  exited with status 1:
Nov 13 13:08:46 myproject-ubuntu systemd[1]: postgresql@12-main.service: Can't open PID file /run/postgresql/12-main.pid (yet?) after start: Operation not permitted
Nov 13 13:08:46 myproject-ubuntu systemd[1]: postgresql@12-main.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Nov 13 13:18:26 myproject-ubuntu postgresql@12-main[1231]: Error: Could not open logfile /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
Nov 13 13:18:26 myproject-ubuntu postgresql@12-main[1215]: Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log -s -o  -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf"  exited with status 1:
Nov 13 13:18:26 myproject-ubuntu systemd[1]: postgresql@12-main.service: Can't open PID file /run/postgresql/12-main.pid (yet?) after start: Operation not permitted
Nov 13 13:18:26 myproject-ubuntu systemd[1]: postgresql@12-main.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Nov 13 13:24:27 myproject-ubuntu gunicorn[1326]:   File "/home/master/.virtualenvs/xxx_django/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
Nov 13 13:24:27 myproject-ubuntu gunicorn[1326]:   File "/home/master/.virtualenvs/xxx_django/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
Nov 13 13:24:27 myproject-ubuntu gunicorn[1326]:   File "/home/master/.virtualenvs/xxx_django/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
Nov 13 13:24:27 myproject-ubuntu gunicorn[1326]:   File "/home/master/.virtualenvs/xxx_django/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
Nov 13 13:24:27 myproject-ubuntu gunicorn[1326]:   File "/home/master/.virtualenvs/xxx_django/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
Nov 13 13:24:27 myproject-ubuntu gunicorn[1326]:   File "/home/master/.virtualenvs/xxx_django/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
Nov 13 13:24:27 myproject-ubuntu gunicorn[1326]:   File "/home/master/.virtualenvs/xxx_django/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
Nov 13 13:24:27 myproject-ubuntu gunicorn[1326]:   File "/home/master/.virtualenvs/xxx_django/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
Nov 13 13:47:42 myproject-ubuntu gunicorn[1330]:   File "/home/master/.virtualenvs/xxx_django/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
Nov 13 13:47:42 myproject-ubuntu gunicorn[1330]:   File "/home/master/.virtualenvs/xxx_django/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
```

Comment: Have you inspected /var/log/postgresql? Seems like it is not running.

Comment: @Steeeve Thanks, I've added the logs at the bottom of the question.

Comment: does the direcory `/var/run/postgresql/` exist? Does the socket `.s.PGSQL.5432` exist in that directory?

Comment: @wildplasser No, I've added `ls` output at the bottom.

Comment: This is just a normal shutdown of postgresql. Don't you have a /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log file? That would be the current one. Can you start it manually? `sudo service postgresql start`

Comment: not there is nothing like that. (I use Postgis extension but that's doesn't change anything I guess). After running the command, nothing happens (no output) and `psql` returns the same error.

Comment: Anything in syslog? Out of disk space? It's getting too complicated for my knowledge level...

Comment: @Steeeve There is something with `pid` file from 2 hours ago.. I've added it to the bottom.

Comment: @Steeeve Disk space is ok, 32GB free.

Comment: `Error: Could not open logfile /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log` - that's why postgresql exits. Try to ouput more lines, not only containing postgresql and `df -h` for the case /var/log is mounted somewhere else